# Does javax.tools depend on the JDK?

Tags: java, java-compiler-api, jsr199

I want to use `JavaCompiler` to dynamically create some classes.

I found the source code of the `javax.tools` package, but there is no implementation; some posts on the internet say it depends on `tools.jar`, I am not sure `tools.jar` associates with JRE.

So, can I run the program in a JRE environment without JDK installed?

Another question, what is the implementation detail of `JavaCompiler`, is it creating a new process to invoke the `javac` command?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JRE's need to include the interfaces, and classes in that package, but do not need to provide implementations.

Sun's JRE doesn't, and returns null from calling [`ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler()).

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566239/options-for-dynamic-compilation-in-java-5) addresses java 5.

Here's a [blog post by Morten Nobel-Jørgensen](http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2008/07/16/using-eclipse-compiler-to-create-dynamic-java-objects-2/) on how to use eclipse's compiler as an implementation of javax.tools.JavaCompiler.

```
JavaCompiler javac = new EclipseCompiler();
```

Comment: thank you, i already finished the coding, but if the getSystemJavaCompiler() returns null, the program would fail. so i need to avoid it

Comment: The blog post link is dead, the updated link is [here](http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2008/07/16/using-eclipse-compiler-to-create-dynamic-java-objects-2/)