# Dynamic Java Compilation: BeanShell, Janino, JavaCompiler?

Tags: java, compilation, dynamic-compilation, janino

I am about to start developing a small Java desktop app. The app is just an engine for which the user provides Java classes to do the work (translating input to output).

I would like the user to provide actual Java classes as files that can be loaded (and reloaded) on the fly.

**For this particular use,** is there any reason why Java would be more cumbersome than Groovy or Beanshell? I'm not asking for a comparison of Groovy/Beanshell and Java as there are many. Rather, I want to know **if it's easier to dynamically load Groovy or Beanshell classes from files** compared to Java.

For Java 1.6, is the [JavaCompiler](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) the best way to dynamically load code? I would like to use all language features so I think Janino is out. Also, any problems with reloading?

**Note: I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616532/on-the-fly-in-memory-java-code-compilation-for-java-5-and-java-6) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566239/options-for-dynamic-compilation-in-java-5)**, but I'm not sure they answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JavaCompiler](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) is very versatile, but it entails a minor, potential configuration problem: In [javax.tools](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html), [ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html) identifies the compiler's class as `com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool`. On some platforms, that class is not part of the JRE; a JDK appears to be required. Here is an [example](http://pscode.org/stbc/).

Also consider [javax.script](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html), discussed [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/). Several [scripting engines](https://scripting.dev.java.net/) are supported.

Comment: Thanks for that. Any reason to prefer something like Rhino over one of the "hot" current languages (Groovy, mostly)?

Comment: I'd guess it would depend on the users' preference. If you target a javax.script compliant implementation, you may be able to allow your users to choose from a list of supported languages.

Comment: Good point. Thanks, still considering, I'll check into the scripting engines too.